# Quasi-random equal assortment

Tags: r, sampling

I am trying to write a script to allocate moderators/second markers to essays that have already been marked but I am struggling to get it right.

There are two main conditions I have:

- As the markers and the moderators are the same group of people, **no moderator should receive an essay they marked** (it should be one of the other moderators);
- The assortment should be as **close to equal** as possible across moderators (roughly equal amounts of essays each).

Let's say markers are AA, AB, AC and AD. And we have 17 papers in total. I can randomly allocate those to the 4 people:

```
library(randomizr)
mod_list = complete_ra(N = 17, num_arms = 4, conditions = markers)
```

Say, 11 papers were allocated fine, but 5 got the same moderator as the marker:

| paperID | marker | moderator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | AA | AA |
| 8 | AD | AD |
| 11 | AC | AC |
| 13 | AA | AA |
| 16 | AB | AB |

If I then use

```
%>%
mutate(no.self = ifelse(moderator == "AA" & marker == "AA",
                          sample(c("AB", "AC", "AD"), 2),
                          ifelse(moderator == "AB" & marker == "AB",
                                 sample(c("AA", "AC", "AD"), 1),
                                 ifelse(moderator == "AC" & marker == "AC",
                                        sample(c("AA", "AB", "AD"), 1),
                                        ifelse(moderator == "AD" & marker == "AD",
                                               sample(c("AA", "AB", "AC"), 1),
                                               moderator)))))
```

the equal assortment disappears.

How can I make sure (1) every moderator needs to second mark **someone else's work**, yet (2) the assortment is **roughly equal** across moderators?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide `dput(x)` where `x` is all 16 rows of `mod_list`; it'll help to explore and (if found) demonstrate the equal-distribution. Does this process ever look at "large numbers" of things to work on, or is it always in the tens or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resample the repeated markers/moderators until the pairs are all different.

```r
library(randomizr)

# brute force, resample until they are all different
shuffle <- function(x, y) {
  while(any(x == y)) {
    y <- sample(y)
  }
  y
}

i <- apply(df1[-1], 1L, \(x) x[1L] == x[2L])
df1$moderator[i] <- shuffle(df1$marker[i], df1$moderator[i])
df1[i, ]
#>    paperID marker moderator
#> 1        1     AD        AA
#> 4        4     AB        AA
#> 8        8     AA        AD
#> 17      17     AA        AB
```

---

## Data

Data creation code.

```r
library(randomizr)

set.seed(2023)
markers <- c("AA", "AB", "AC", "AD")
mark_list <- complete_ra(N = 17, num_arms = 4, conditions = markers) |> as.character()
mod_list <- complete_ra(N = 17, num_arms = 4, conditions = markers) |> as.character()
paperID <- seq.int(17)

df1 <- data.frame(paperID, marker = mark_list, moderator = mod_list)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking as a possible solution but I am not good at writing functions (yet). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need cryptographic levels of randomisation and some determinism is OK, maybe something like this could work?

```
set.seed(1)
marker <- factor(sample(rep(c("AA", "AB", "AC", "AD"), length.out=10)))
moderator <- structure((as.integer(marker)) %% max(as.integer(marker)) + 1, 
  levels=levels(marker), class="factor")
dtf <- data.frame(paperID=seq_along(marker), marker, moderator)
str(dtf)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ paperID  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#  $ marker   : Factor w/ 4 levels "AA","AB","AC",..: 3 4 1 3 2 4 1 2 2 1
#  $ moderator: Factor w/ 4 levels "AA","AB","AC",..: 4 1 2 4 3 1 2 3 3 2
```

The moderators follow the same pattern as the markers, but AA becomes AB, AB becomes AC, and so on, guaranteeing agains repeats.

---

Another approach, this time also guaranteeing to share the workload as evenly as possible.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 110

mm <- sort(rep(c("AA", "AB", "AC", "AD"), length.out=n*2))
mm <- matrix(mm, n, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(mm) <- c("marker", "moderator")
mm[,2] <- c(mm[((n %/% 2)+1):n, 2], mm[1:(n %/% 2), 2])
mm <- data.frame(paperID=sample(1:n), mm)
mm <- mm[order(mm[[1]]),]
rownames(mm) <- NULL

head(mm)
#   paperID marker moderator
# 1       1     AD        AB
# 2       2     AA        AC
# 3       3     AD        AB
# 4       4     AB        AD
# 5       5     AD        AB
# 6       6     AC        AA
#
any(mm[, 2] == mm[, 3])
# [1] FALSE
table(mm[, 2])
# 
# AA AB AC AD 
# 28 27 28 27 
table(mm[, 3])
# 
# AA AB AC AD 
# 27 28 27 28 
table(unlist(mm[, 2:3]))
# 
# AA AB AC AD 
# 55 55 55 55
```

---

A third option, this time making sure the crossing between markers and moderators are as equal as possible, meaning each marker-moderator pair is equally possible

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 120
nam <- c("AA", "AB", "AC", "AD")

eg <- as.matrix(expand.grid(marker=1:length(nam), moderator=1:length(nam)))
eg <- eg[eg[, 1] != eg[, 2], ]
eg <- eg[order(eg[, 1] - eg[, 2]),]
rownames(eg) <- NULL
eg[] <- nam[eg]
eg <- eg[sample(rep(1:nrow(eg), length.out=n)),]
dtf <- data.frame(paperID=1:n, eg)

head(dtf)
#   paperID marker moderator
# 1       1     AC        AB
# 2       2     AD        AC
# 3       3     AC        AB
# 4       4     AD        AB
# 5       5     AD        AA
# 6       6     AC        AB

table(dtf[,-1])
#       moderator
# marker AA AB AC AD
#     AA  0 10 10 10
#     AB 10  0 10 10
#     AC 10 10  0 10
#     AD 10 10 10  0
```

Comment: This takes care of the "shouldn't moderate your own marking" stuff, but it didn't solve the equal assortment issue. Thank you, though!

Comment: @kozmix: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean by equal assortment, but this solution divides the workload as equal as possible between the markers, equally equal as Rui's solution.

Comment: @kozmix: I added some new variants improving on assortment in a couple of different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Using *RcppAlgos* candies.

```
> set.seed(42)
> data.frame(pid, RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(v, 2)[
+   sample.int(RcppAlgos::permuteCount(v, 2), length(pid), replace=TRUE), ])
  pid X1 X2
1   3 AA AB
2   8 AB AC
3  11 AA AB
4  13 AC AD
5  16 AD AA
```

---

*Data:*

```
v <- c("AA", "AB", "AC", "AD")
pid <- c(3, 8, 11, 13, 16)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works as well! It just includes the extra step of me having to select the marker-moderator matches.